# How does APPLY_KMEANS work in Vertica

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, vertica

I am testing the machine learning tools in Vertica. I understand how the `KMEANS` work since it just devides the data into clusters. However I do not understand how the `APPLY_KMEANS` works on new data. 
It looks to me like it acts more like a classification method. Since it classifies new Data in the existing clusters. So what algorithm is used (K nearest neighbor)?  Its not very clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*k*-means is a **clustering** algorithm (not classification!) that iterates over 2 steps:

- **Assignement step:** Assign each point a centroid
- **Update step:** update centroids coordinates

When you build your k-means model, you first initialize centroids (different strategy, can be random initialization), then you iterate until your clustering is ok (your error is below a given threshold).

What defines your model is actually your centroids.

When using `APPLY_KMEANS` you will run an assignment step using data from your query and centroids from your model. Points will then be assigned to clusters depending on their distance with respect to centroids.

Hope it helps
`pltrdy`

---

**Note about Clustering vs Classification:**
We can be tempted to think that clustering is a kind of classification. Still, classification must only refer to [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) while clustering corresponds to [unsupervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsupervised_learning). Thus, don't do it :)

Comment: The way you put it, it seems that the APPLY_KMEANS is a Classification, since it is only doing the assignment step. So K-means is basically the training in regards to APPLY_KMEANS. When using K-means by itself than it is an unsupervised clustering algorithm. When using APPLY_KMEANS with new data the the centroids coordinates are not changing, is that correct? Which would make it a classification algorithm, no?

Comment: It do make sense. k-means is a clustering algorithm not a classification one. Still, "apply kmeans" is actually another algorithm using k-means model centroids to classify data. Thus, can be seen as a multilabel classification algorithm. I still say "can be seen" because I find this ambiguous so it should not appear as "apply kmeans = classification" as it would be missleading. But you got the point.